# W3C HTML validator no longer accepts scoped styles

Tags: html, stylesheet, w3c-validation

The following code used to validate OK on W3C a few months back:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Page Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css" scoped></style>
        test content 
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently the validator throws:

> Element `style` not allowed as child of element `body` in this context.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scoped styles have been removed from HTML.

They do not appear in [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) or [HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), and have been removed from [Living HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element). (You can find a spec for them in a [**draft** of HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-html51-20160310/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) but it didn't make it to the final version).

[Browser support is dying](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped), Chrome *removed* support for them and only Firefox currently does support them.

The validator reports them as an error because they are now an error. Stop using them.